# Connect via SSH to the main display active terminal

Tags: ssh, hdmi, display, remote

My Raspberry Pi reboot to the terminal and not the desktop environment.
I got a video display connected to it through the HDMI.

I would like to connect to that Pi via SSH from my PC and remote control the active terminal session that is displayed on the HDMI.
Not a new SSH session and not an X session via VNC.

But only the actual terminal session displayed on the screen right now.
And control it via my keyboard and mouse (preferably with Putty SSH connection).

Can this be achieved ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You could do that if you set it to join a [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) or [tmux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) session on boot, then you could share the same session if you wanted via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question your Pi rebooted, and now, on the HDMI display you are either being prompted for a username/password, or your Pi logged you in automatically and is now sitting at the command line. At this point you could use PuTTY / SSH to log in remotely from your PC, but you will not be able to "take over" the local session that is currently displayed on your HDMI display.

It is possible to control your Pi remotely and have the HDMI display reflect what you're doing--just not through PuTTY and SSH alone. As you pointed out you could could share the Pi's desktop with VNC. It looks like user1133275's suggestion is another possibility. I haven't tried the tools he suggests but they look like they might be just the ticket.